# Replace Month name with month number

Tags: pandas, datetime, replace

I have a column called 'date' with object data type(pandas) as following:

```
Apr-12
Apr-12
Mar-12
Apr-12
Apr-12
```

Name: date, dtype: object

i want to replace this column like the following format in same formate

```
04/12
04/12
03/12
04/12
04/12
```

Name: date, dtype: object

Comment: Can you post code to generate dataframe of that type?

Comment: i didnt genrate the dataframe i just imported my csv into pandas and its coming like this

Comment: Okay. I wrote an answer. see if that works for ya

Answer (score 0):

You could try this but I am not sure if this will work.Let me know the error and also please postcode to generate a dataframe of that kind.

```
from datetime import datetime
df['month'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(datetime.strptime(x,'%b-%d')).month)
```

Edit:
I checked this and it works. Similarly, you can do for year and then get the format you want

Edit2:
 I ran the following code by creating a demo dataframe and it works. You could try printing the month col

```
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':['Apr-12','Mar-13']})
df['month'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(datetime.strptime(x,'%b-%d')).month)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'TimeStamp'

Comment: not working bro showing following error:                                                AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'TimeStamp'

Comment: Please check my edit. I am converting it to datetime object and then to timestamp to get month

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `to_datetime`

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date,format='%b-%d').dt.strftime('%m/%d')
Out[405]: 
0    04/12
1    03/12
2    04/12
3    04/12
Name: date, dtype: object
#df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date,format='%b-%d').dt.strftime('%m/%d')
```